# Invoking iMacros script from another iMacros script

Tags: imacros

Suppose I have 2 iMacros scripts script1.iim and script2.iim, is there anyway to invoke script2.iim from within script1.iim?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can use JavaScript scripting for that purpose. Place `script1.iim` and `script2.iim` in the same folder as `#Current.iim`

Then you can make a JavaScript and name it `test.js` . In it place these codes.

```
iimPlay("script1.iim")
iimPlay("script2.iim")
```

Comment: Hi IceD, I usually run script1.iim and script2.iim on a webpage say http://abc.com/xyz.html by running them using iMacros firefox plugin. How can I do the same using test.js i.e. how can I run test.js on the webpage http://abc.com/xyz.html in firefox?

Comment: Resolved. Was able to run the js using the imacros extension itself.

Answer (score 0):

a simple option is to combine the two scripts

Comment: I cant combine the scripts as each script does a specific task and the need of running a master script is incase any of the individual scripts fail when running the master script, I will then run the failed script individually.

Comment: i suggest you then use the java script way.